# Golang getting an undefined type error when using a struct

Tags: go

I am using a thread-pool example from http://marcio.io/2015/07/handling-1-million-requests-per-minute-with-golang/ and I am following that tutorial however I am getting this error on compile **d.pool undefined (type *Dispatcher has no field or method pool)** this is the code

```
   type Dispatcher struct {
        // A pool of workers channels that are registered with the dispatcher
        WorkerPool chan chan Job
    }

     func NewWorker(workerPool chan chan Job) Worker {
    return Worker{
        WorkerPool: workerPool,
        JobChannel: make(chan Job),
        quit:       make(chan bool)}
}

    func NewDispatcher(maxWorkers int) *Dispatcher {
        pool := make(chan chan Job, maxWorkers)
        return &Dispatcher{WorkerPool: pool}
    }



    func (d *Dispatcher) Run() {
        // starting n number of workers
           //d.WorkerPool

        for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
            worker := NewWorker(d.pool)
            worker.Start()
        }

        go d.dispatch()
    }
```

The error is happening with this code

**worker := NewWorker(d.pool)**

Any solutions or suggestions would be great as I am new to this but am trying to implement a thread pool

Comment: have you tried to remove : just do worker = NewWorker(d.pool)

Comment: There is no field `pool` in `Dispatcher`. It only has `WorkerPool`.

Comment: Yeah not sure how that guys code can work your Dispatcher object doesn't have a pool so d.pool can never work.

Answer (score 0):

The error means exactly what it says, your `Dispatcher` type has no field or method named `pool`. It does, however, have a field named `WorkerPool`, which is what I'm guessing you meant to reference.